# is the set of integers as big as P(prime numbers)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to P(\mathbb{P})$ where $f(x) = \{prime\ factors\ of\ x\}$

$f$ is not $1:1$ (easy)

I proved that $f$ is on $P(\mathbb{P})$ which is probably wrong since it means $|\mathbb{N}|\geq |P(\mathbb{P})|$ but $|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{P}|$.

Every subset of primes has a source in $\mathbb{N}$ (the multiplication of all the primes)

What's wrong with this?

Comment: There is no $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)=\mathbb{P}\in P(\mathbb{P}).$ That is, the function is not surjective.

Comment: The set of integers is "as big as" the set of the primes because the set of primes is an infinite subset of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z$ is countable.

Comment: As @mfl pointed out, every *finite* set of primes has a source in $\mathbb{N}$. However, no infinite subset $X$ of primes can be $f(n)$ for any natural number $n$, so $f$ cannot be onto.

Comment: I think you mean that $f(x)$ is the set of *distinct* prime factors of $x$, otherwise you are defining a correspondence..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every finite set of primes is in the range of $f$.

However, what about any *infinite* set of primes? Say, the set of all primes, itself?

No number has infinitely many prime factors, so no infinite set of primes is in the range of $f$. Indeed, the set of *finite* sets of primes is countable, while the set of *infinite* sets of primes is uncountable - "most" sets of primes are infinite!

Answer (score 0):

You already saw your mistake: the cardinality of the power set of an infinite set is strictly greater than the cardinality of the set itself.

Since $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ have the same cardinality, then $f$ cannot be onto (as mentioned before, indeed, every integer $\ge 2$ has a finite number of distinct prime factors).

Answer (score -1):

As someone pointed out in the comments, $\mathbb{N}$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{P}$ because they are both infinite subsets of the countably infinite set $\mathbb{Z}$, hence they are both countably infinite sets. If you want to see this explicitly, just define $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{P}$ letting $f(n)$ be the $n$th prime, i.e. $f(1) = 2, f(2) = 3, f(3) = 5,\ldots$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's fundamental question, which is "why does the argument in the OP fail?"